# Save/retrieve data by foreign key (API)

Tags: ios, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I'm attempting to set up my API for iOS app. This is my first time to use Laravel as a API so here is what I have in my tables:

**Cars**

```
Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('age')->nullable();
        $table->string('model')->nullable();
        $table->string('color')->nullable();
```

**Users**

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('street')->nullable();
        $table->string('niehgborhood')->nullable();
        $table->string('city')->nullable();
```

**Contract**

```
$table->increments('id');

        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned;
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

        $table->integer('car_id')->unsigned;
        $table->foreign('car_id')->references('id')->on('cars');
```

**Models**

```
protected $table = 'users';

protected $guarded = ['id'];
protected $fillable = ['phone', 'email',
    'street','city','niehgborhood'
    ,'national_id'];

public function cars()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

Users

```
 protected $guarded = ['id'];

protected $fillable = ['name', 'age',
     'color, model'
    ];


public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cars');
}
```

in my controller I'm familiar with saving requested data

```
$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();

    $user->phone = $request->phone;
    $user->city = $request->city;

    $user->save();
```

my goal with this project is to display the data(contracts) saved by iOS app users in my dashboard. For example, users info and the cars they are interested in my table. Can someone help me with what to do query in the controller(not views). Or provide helpful links for projects like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your relation between `User` and `Cars` should be [`many-to-many`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). Please read the docs to apply this relation properly.

If your relations are in the place then you can do as:

```
$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();

$cars = $user->cars; // returns collection of cars associated with the user.
```

For example - In your `User` model define the following relation:

```
public function cars()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Car');
}
```

**Update**

To save the user and associate cars, you can do it as following:

```
$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();

$user->phone = $request->phone;
$user->city = $request->city;

$user->save();

$car_ids = $request->car_ids; // it should return an array

$user->cars()->sync($car_ids);
```

There is more way  to store the data. Please read the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) for more info.

Comment: so this will return cars associated with the user. Now before returning that how can I link them ? How can I link the cars id to users id by http calls ? @iCode

Comment: Check the updated answer. For linking the data read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships). And I didn't get your question "How can I link the cars id to users id by http calls ?"

Comment: thank you for your example! What I meant is that in the  iOSapp I'll send users data ( name ,phone...) to a `store` function in Laravel. Same will happen to cars data. But as I said I want to display users info and what cars they are interested in. How can do that ? in the app I have a form that users will fill out consist of their info and they cars they are interested in( dropdowns) @iCode

Comment: this `$car_ids = $request->car_ids; // it should return an array
` will return an array if the cars_id was sent in the request, right? What I'm trying to do is I have two forms in my iOS app the first one is for users to fill out their info then next the fill out the cars info that they would like to rent. Two separate tables but I want to gather them in my contact table as I showed in my question. The User info will go to User table and Cars info will go to Cars table but to associate them by IDs is my issue. Can you help me, please? Thank you

Comment: Yes, you have understood it correctly. For your second question, try to use the same form for user info and his car interests. Or the second option is to create a form which returns the newly created user and then you can use this user's id to send in the second form. In your controller find the user and associate the interests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129717/discussion-between-leo0019-and-icode).